# How would I change a voice channel's bitrate using discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a voice channel that I would like to change the bitrate of, but I can't find any ways of doing it in the docs. How would I do it?

Edit:
I've figured it out, you have to fetch the channel from id and change it from there.

```py
vchannel = await self.fetch_channel(id)
await vchannel.edit(bitrate=96000)
```

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to use [client.get_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.get_channel) instead of [client.fetch_channel](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.fetch_channel) because it's not an API call so you won't be ratelimited, and it will be faster.

The second problem in your code is that you used `self`, good, but you didn't put `client` (or `bot`, depdending of what you set) after it.

For me your code must be :

```
vchannel = self.client.get_channel(id)
await vchannel.edit(bitrate=96000)
```

Have a nice day!